# How to detect if user clicked on an image on a map in Android?

Tags: java, android, dictionary, listener, onclicklistener

I have a map in my app and that has circles plotted on them, like seen in the image, three png images A, B and C.
[image]
I want to highlight one of these images, when the user precisely intends to tap on them to do some action pertaining to them.
In order to achieve this,I am using a very crude method

```
            for(int i = 0; i < vectorPts.size(); i ++){
                dest_location.setLatitude(vectorPts.get(i).x);
                dest_location.setLongitude(vectorPts.get(i).y);                 
                double distance = (double) mylocation.distanceTo(dest_location);
                distanceCollect.add(distance);  
                 int minIndex = distanceCollect.indexOf(Collections.min(distanceCollect));
                 System.out.println("The value >> " + minIndex + DSS.activeRoute);
                 indexUnderEdit = minIndex;                                                                 
            }
```

The Vector vectorPts of points has all the points coordinates. I am using the distanceTo method to find the distance between the click point and the location of the images. The least distance between the click point and the actual image location means the user intended to click that image is my assumption. But this is a weak apporach, because any clicks any where on the map (far from any images) will also be considered and the shortest distance will be selected. Can you suggest me an alternate way to find on which specific image the user clicked.

```
@Override
    public void drawRoute(Canvas canvas,String routeName,MapActivity mact) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                                                      
        if((routeName == null || (routeName.equals(PROJ.currentRoute.activeRouteName)))){               
        if (cpts.size() > 0)
       {   
           if (this.wktType == WKTType.ePolyLine || this.wktType == WKTType.ePolyLineM)
           {                   
            if ( mPath != null)
                canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPen);                       
           }

           // draw point icons
           Resources Res = PROJ.getInstance().getResources();
           int i = 0;
           for(; i < cpts.size(); i++)
           {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                // Draw start point //                                      
                if(this.angleRecieved >= 0){                    
                    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Res,  R.drawable.startpoint);                                                             
                    canvas.drawBitmap( img,  cpts.get(i).x - img.getWidth()+2, cpts.get(i).y - (img.getHeight()/2) , null);                     
                }
                else{                                           
                    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Res, R.drawable.startpoint_inv);                  
                    canvas.drawBitmap( img,  cpts.get(i).x-3 , cpts.get(i).y - (img.getHeight()/2), null);
                }                                           
            }
            else if((i == cpts.size() - 1)&&(bIsFinished == true))
            {                   
                // Draw end point                   
                if(this.angleRecievedFinish >= 0){                                
                    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Res,R.drawable.finishpoint); 
                    canvas.drawBitmap( img,  cpts.get(i).x - img.getWidth()+2, cpts.get(i).y - (img.getHeight()/2), null);
                    }
                    else{                        
                    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Res, R.drawable.finishpoint_inv); 
                    canvas.drawBitmap( img,  cpts.get(i).x-3 , cpts.get(i).y - (img.getHeight()/2), null);
                    }  

                if(!bIsSaved){                  
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Constants.CUSTOM_NEWMESSAGE_INTENT);
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.EVENT_STRING, Constants.mapEvents.ROUTE_FINISHED);
                    PROJ.getCurrentApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
                    bIsSaved = true;                    
                }                                                                                                                                      
            }
            else
            //Draw intermediate points from 1 to 10
            {                       
                if (i ==1){
                    this.forFirstIteration = this.angleRecieved;                        
                }
                if(i == 10){
                    this.lastNotifier = true;                       
                }
                int wpResId = getWPResourceId(i);
                Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Res, wpResId);                    
                canvas.drawBitmap( img,  cpts.get(i).x - img.getWidth()/2, cpts.get(i).y -  img.getWidth()/2, null);
            }

           }
       }

    }   
}
```

Comment: How are you adding the images to your map? Could you post that code.

Comment: HI Tom, I have added the code that adds images to my map